# Separate CSS files for multi-page app in Astro with Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, postcss, astrojs

I have 6 pages in astro with tailwind which combines css from all pages into a single css file of ~75KB.

I need to split it and reduce the css file size for each page load.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What version of Tailwind do you have in dependencies? It can be done with v3.2+ using [@config](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#config) directive

Comment: Tailwind - v3.0.24. Then I need to have multiple css files and import it for each page?

Comment: yes and every file should point to its own config. I would recomend to update Tailwind to v3.2

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I’ve just wanted the same and have discussed in Astro’s Discord.